# UPDATE or DELETE table row depending on existing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table `A` with `Name nvarchar(200) UNIQUE` column. I have written a function working simular to `NormalizeSpace`(trim + collapse multiple spaces to single one), the question is how to write a script that will `UPDATE` or `DELETE` `Name` column dependig on is normalized Name already exists in table or not: if not exists `UPDATE`, else `DELETE`.

Example:

```
  'a bc' 
  ' a  bc'
  ' d  e'
```

Will result:

```
  'a bc'
  'd e'
```

Thank you.

Comment: How exactly do you propose updating the row when it doesn't exist??? You need to provide some information here so we can help. This would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: So is this effectively a function that you want to apply to existing rows in a table? Or is this for new data that you want to write, with a trigger to apply to inserted rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two steps (or 1 if you use `merge`):

```
-- Remove all but one copy of each value
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dbo.NormalizeSpace(col) order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) 
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;

-- Now update the values to be normalized:
update t
    set col = dbo.NormalizeSpace(col)
    where col <> dbo.NormalizeSpace(col);
```

Comment: I was doing the same but I assume there is some ID involve. So instead `order by (select null)` I would recomend `order by ID` so you can keep the first one,.